# ffmpeg stream new image every x seconds to youtube

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, youtube

I know how to stream a single image with sound to youtube via ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i music.txt -loop 1 -i input.png -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/****
```

with music.txt being:

```
file sound.mp3
file sound.mp3
file sound.mp3
```

How do I stream multiple images now? for instance first input000.png then 1 sec later, input001.png then 1 sec later, input002.png  etc...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you as the input:

```
-r 1 -i input%03d.png
```

`-r 1` sets the framerate to 1 per second

`input%03d.png` uses the set of images (`input000.png`, `input001.png`, and so on) as the input